# Help! Unconfirmed transaction for the past 12 hours!

Tags: bitcoin-core, unconfirmed-transactions, bitcoin-core-development

[image: I am a noob in the bitcoin world]

I am a noob in the bitcoin world, I made a transfer of 0.0577201 BTC , with a transaction fee of 0.000221 BTC,  but the transaction has not yet been confirmed. Please help me! Here is the link for the transaction: https://blockchain.info/tx/72b2b1191693f5d916daf899ef6e43171599b065779e394fc7096c8fc5262091

Comment: It confirmed now.

Answer (score 0):

[There is currently a backlog of about 69,000 unconfirmed Bitcoin transactions](https://blockchain.info/unconfirmed-transactions) and only the transactions with the highest fees will be confirmed until the backlog clears.

> Please help me!

For similar situations going forward, you have a few options:

1. Submit your transaction to the [ViaBTC Transaction Accelerator](https://www.viabtc.com/tools/txaccelerator/)
2. If you control either of the receiving addresses, send a new transaction from one of them with a much larger fee, encouraging a miner to pick up the whole chain of transactions (Child-Pays-For-Parent).
3. Wait. The transaction should be either confirmed or removed from the memory pool within about 72 hours.

[21.co has a good fee estimator for future transactions.](https://bitcoinfees.21.co/)